# Date formating in QGIS using expression?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing

My expression:

```
day(now()) || '/' || month(now()) || '/' || year(now())
```

returns current date as 15/4/2019, but I want to get the date in dd/mm/yyyy format i.e. 15/04/2019.

How can I get that using QGIS desktop version 2.18.12?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `format_date` expression.

```
format_date(now(),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Please read the documentation of the `format_date` expression in QGIS Expression dialog to have all possibilities.

[image]

Comment: It returns date like 15/53/2019....which is impossible.

Comment: QGIS 2.18.12 is very old. The last of the 2.18 is 2.18.28 from January 2019. Maybe a bug has been fixed in the mean time? And QGIS 2.18 is not maintained anymore. Do you have the `MM` expression in your expression dialog documentation?

Comment: Yeah, 'MM' seems to be working fine, I think 2.18 wrongly reads 'mm'.

Comment: `MM` is working fine for me on 2.18.28